# linq query throws EntryPointNotFoundException if using extension method from different project but works fine if extension method is in same project

Tags: c#, linq, dynamic, com, extension-methods

I am working in a project A. There is a reference to project B (part of the same solution) which contains the following extension method:

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static IDictionary<string, Component2> GetAllComponentsByName(this AssemblyDoc assyDoc) =>
        ((object[])assyDoc.GetComponents(false)).Cast<Component2>().ToDictionary(c => c.Name2, c => c);
}
```

When using it in my code in project A like so

```
public void DoSth(AssemblyDoc assyDoc)
{
    var x = assyDoc.GetAllComponentsByName();
    var y = x.OrderBy(kv => kv.Key).ToArray();
}
```

then the `OrderBy` query (more precisely: it's enumeration due to `ToArray`) throws an `EntryPointNotFoundException`.

But if I put the `Extensions` class inside project A instead, it works fine.

**Any idea why that is so? Any idea what I can do to be able to use the extension method from project B?**

(I have other projects in this solution that also need to use that extension method, and I do not want to repeat code.)

Here is some information about the classes used:

- I am writing a SolidWorks Addin; this is done by writing a class library in a certain way, using SolidWorks API. The SolidWorks API assemblies were installed using nuget.
- SolidWorks is written in C++.
- The SolidWorks API objects are COM objects. `AssemblyDoc` and `Component2` are such COM objects.
- The method `AssemblyDoc.GetComponents(bool)` returns `dynamic`, but from the documentation I know that the actual returned object is `object[]` where each item represents a `Component2`. That's why I first cast to `object[]` and then use `Cast<Component2>`.
- The method `Component2.Name2` returns a `string`.

Comment: That is an awfully strange exception to get in this scenario.  You'd certainly risk FileNotFoundException since the odds are so low that the CLR can find the dependent assembly.  And you haven't mentioned at all what you did to help it succeed.  Maybe it found one, but just the completely wrong dll.  Hmm.  Use SysInternals' ProcMon to verify this.

Comment: I don't understand 1.) why the CLR should not be able to find dependent assemblies. I installed all necessary SolidWorks APIs via nuget. And the extension method/class is part of the same solution; there is a reference to project B in project A. 2.) what else you expect me to say how I made it work: I said I put the extension class into project A (cut/paste). That was all.